# trigger works for system admin/integration user but not for other profiles in salesforce

Tags: apex, trigger

```
Trigger CaseTrigger on Case (after update, after insert, Before Insert, Before Update){
    Trigger_Switch__c objTriggerSwitch = Trigger_Switch__c.getValues('Case');

    Boolean checkRecType=false;
    string OCRecordType = System.label.LP_Merchant_Record_Type;
    List<string> recTypeList = OCRecordType.split(',');
    for(Case cs : trigger.New){
        if(String.isNotBlank(cs.RecordTypeId) && recTypeList.contains(cs.RecordTypeId)) 
            checkRecType=true;
        else 
            checkRecType=false;
    }

    if(objTriggerSwitch != null && objTriggerSwitch.Active__c){    
        if(Trigger.isAfter){
            if(Trigger.isInsert){                
                if(checkRecType) 
                   myClass.afterInsertHandler(Trigger.new);
                else 
                    CaseTriggerHandler.afterInsertHandler(Trigger.new);
            }    
            if(Trigger.isUpdate) {                
                if(checkRecType) {
                    myClass.afterUpdateHandler(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);

                }else 
                    CaseTriggerHandler.afterUpdateHandler(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);
                system.debug('######## '+CaseTriggerHandler.isTriggerExecuted);                
            }   
        }

        else if(Trigger.isBefore){
            if(Trigger.isInsert){
                if(checkRecType)
                    myClass.beforeInsertHandler(trigger.New);
                else                    
                  CaseTriggerHandler.beforeInsertHandler(Trigger.new);                
            }    

            if(Trigger.isUpdate){
                if(checkRecType)
                    myClass.beforeUpdateHandlerForOneCare(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);
                else
                  CaseTriggerHandler.beforeUpdateHandler(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);                
            }    
        }
    }    
}
```

this trigger is calling myClass whose code is as follows

```
public class myClass {

    public static void beforeInsertHandler(List<Case> triggerNew){
        updateExpectedCloserDate(triggerNew);
        Set<string> accIds = New Set<string>();
        boolean checkrecordtype=false;
        Enable_Objects__c enableObj = Enable_Objects__c.getValues('Case');  
        for(Case cs : triggerNew){
            system.debug('-->> 12 '+cs.Record_Type__c);
            if(cs.Record_Type__c == 'abc' || cs.Record_Type__c == 'abc1' || cs.Record_Type__c == 'xyz' || cs.Record_Type__c == 'xyz1'){
                SystemUtility.getIdentifierUUID(cs, 'Identifier__c', enableObj);
                cs.TATValue__c = cs.LP_TAT__c != Null ? integer.valueOf(cs.LP_TAT__c) : 0 ;
                cs.Failed_Attachment_Count__c = 0;
            }  
            if(string.isNotBlank(cs.AccountId)){
                accIds.add(cs.AccountId);
            }
        }
        Map<Id,String> case_userQueueIdMap = New Map<Id,String>();
        getCurrentQueueName(case_userQueueIdMap);
        map<id,case> OldCaseMap = new map<id,case>();

        updateOpportunityFieldToCase(triggerNew,OldCaseMap);
         updateLOBname(triggerNew,case_userQueueIdMap);
      updateEntitlementProcess(triggerNew,accIds);

    }
```

the problem is all this logic is working fine in test environment but not in production, and the weird part is when I try to trace the error through debug logs (which is created for integration user and debug level is set to integration debug) it starts working fine, as soon as my debug logs ends before insert logic stops working.

Only **SystemUtility.getIdentifierUUID(cs, 'Identifier__c', enableObj);** is working fine in all condition(either debug log is on/off). This is only happening at the time of insertion, update is working fine.

Comment: Hi - can you give us more details?  You said "which is getting generated by a 3rd party interface" - do you mean from an AppExchange app or a managed package so you can't see the actual trigger code?

Comment: no, not by app exchange or managed package... its like the front end is a web page(based on React) we have integrated it with our SF org.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here to provide an answer. What is the trigger doing? Does it use any functionality to turn itself on and off on a per-user basis? How do you know it's not just throwing an exception for other users? Can you provide the code and a reproducible example where it works and does not work, and be specific about what working means?

Comment: Hi David,
trigger is executing on the basis of recordtype of the case, there is no such condition for per-user basis

Comment: If it's working fine in test, but not in prod then the issue seems to be with configuration parameters you are using. In above code, it seems you are using custom setting 'objTriggerSwitch' can you check if its field Active__ is properly mapped , also does the label - LP_Merchant_Record_Type is properly configured on prod.

Comment: but then if these config settings have some issue, why is it that, when I am turning debug logs on, its starts working fine?